# smartgwt drawing

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am new to GWT and working on a project involving RPC and MySQL. I want to dynamically draw a network diagram which includes ovals and lines with arrows. I am considering using SmartGWT DrawOval and DrawLinePath.

1) Does it make sense to use SmartGWT for only drawing shapes and using GWT for other things like layouts/widgets/RPC/etc?

2)I know that it is recommended to not mix GWT and SmartGWT, so I want to know if I can safely use drawing widgets with other GWT components.

3) Is there better alternative than SmartGWT for drawing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Nope, your approach is not a good one because of the answer to your second one.
2. No, it is not safe, as it is not recommended. Better only use SmartGWT components for your UI elements. But I suspect that you are a bit confused here. Only UI elements are not to be mixed. All the other facilities of GWT (i.e. RPC mechanisms), can, and actually will be required to, be part of your solution.
3. I see the following options:

   - Use SmartGWT UI elements for all your layers/widgets and of course use the drawing shapes you have identified to create your solution.
   - Use GWT elements and use other drawing libraries to achieve your goals. Such can be: [gwt-connectors](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-connectors/), [raphaelgwt](http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/), [lib-gwt-svg](http://code.google.com/p/lib-gwt-svg/), depending whether connectors or simple lines are enough for your specifications.
   - Use SmartGWT UI elements and embed one of the above libraries to cover cases that the provided elements can't support. This can be tricky as the success of such marriage is not always guaranteed, but it can't be dismissed either. I had success, with such an approach, by using the lib-gwt-svg.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand it a bit better now.

I need to draw data flow (lines with arrows) between network components. I looked at the drawing libs you mentioned and others but found only in SmartGWT and gwt-links lib. The gwt-links have dnd (drag and drop) which I don't want and cannot be disabled. So I guess I have to go with SmartGWT.

Comment: Check the small getting started example: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-links/wiki/GettingStarted. If you omit the last step, you won't register a DnD controller, so that functionality won't be part of your application. SmartGwt and gwt-links might not be compatible to each other though, so you probably will have to go down the vanilla GWT path.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. Based on your experience, what do you think would be easy and faster for UI development - GWT Designer or SmartGWT? I have no experience in either of them.

Comment: I have been using SmartGWT for 3 years now, so for me it is easier to use that. But I can remember the initial frustration I had with various objects of the framework. Of course that happens with any new framework we learn :D. Regarding GWT Designer I have never used it, but I believe for something straightforward and typical it can be a speed multiplier tool. I am afraid your case requires a bit deeper depth though. If you do not need fancy or specialized UI elements GWT is lighter, SmartGWT provides many elements ready to use, but can be heavier for simpler cases.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I am going to use SmartGWT for drawing only, and GWT Designer for rest of the UI. I guess that should work. My project is an internal tool to display certain data in various format and doesn't need to be fancy. If GWT and SmartGWT cannot co-exist, I will switch to SmartGWT.

Comment: After experimenting with GWT Designer, I have decided to use only smartGWT for UI.